# Where is the error calling the class in java?

Tags: java, class

I can't understand why it is showing a error when I am calling the class "Action".

```
import java.util.*;

public class Banks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Actions act = new Actions();

        System.out.println("How much money would you like to withdrawl?");
        double moneygrabber = scan.nextDouble();

        act.take(6.24);

    }

    class Actions {
        private double balance = 0;
        private double withdrawl;
        private double deposit;

        void withdrawl(int take) {
            this.balance = this.balance - take;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, you haven't defined take method. It shouldn't compile.

Comment: What 'error' is it showing? Can your code compile? If no, what does the stacktrace say? Is it while running? Again: what does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: Also note that you don't call a *class* - you call a *method* (or constructor). Which method do you think you're calling? Where is it declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withdrawl` is the method in `Actions` class which accepts integer (parameter name is take and not the method name, you use method name while calling from the class instance act in your case) and not double.

Instead of

```
act.take(6.24);
```

Use

```
act.withdrawl(6);
```

if you want to pass double (numbers with decimal), you should change your method argument type from int to double like

```
void withdrawl(double take)
               ^^^^^^
```

Comment: and change the signature to `void withdrawl(double take)`